# Using Xcode UIAutomation, how can I bring my backgrounded application back to the foreground on the iPhone?

Tags: xcode, ui-automation

I guess really the long and short of this is how can I manage to bring my application from the background state to the foreground state via Xcode UIAutomation?

Any thoughts anyone...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to pop your backgrounded app to the foreground in front of any other app the user may be running? No. You cannot do that. That would be confusing to the user (they're playing a game and suddenly your app is frontmost; text messages and battery alerts are bad enough).

Comment: not sure why this is marked as answer; the user has stated he wants to do this via UI Automation, thereby implying that it is for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 10):

You send the app to the background with a duration, it then reactivates automatically. So for example, to send the app to the background for 30 seconds:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(30);
```